# Absence of chat notification makes me focus on work. Help!

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, google-chrome, audio

For a while now the chat notifications don't seem to be playing for me any more while in chat. (The Tavern on MSE, if that matters) I am on Chrome Version 36.0.1985.125 m on Windows 7.

Audio in general works just fine on my computer and in the browser. The sound notification is set to "when mentioned". (Or apparently so. I haven't changed anything there).

> [image]

Playing the mp3 directly by going to http://cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/meta.mp3 works just fine. I get no errors in the console either upon notification.

Can anyone else reproduce this issue? Any hints as to what I could try to be annoyed again by that sound?

Comment: Is this a bug? I have to admit I disable the audio for every chat room - from a productivity perspective, you should avoid being driven by the notification. Visit the room when you want... Productivity Stack Exchange FTW :-)

Comment: And no, I can't reproduce it, sorry

Comment: *"Visit the room when you want"* ... I'm afraid we're far beyond that point @RoryAlsop

Comment: Yep, I've been having the same issue since yesterday. Stupid chat devs, Y U NO FIX! ... oh wait

Comment: Myeah, maybe I should have just pinged you @balpha .... ah

Comment: @RoryAlsop: I just reproduced it. Bart pinged me in the room, no sound was played.

Comment: Strangely it's only on chat.meta, but works fine on chat.so and chat.se. Can you confirm that? Maybe it's an issue with the audio file encoding that the newest Chrome version doesn't handle anymore.

Comment: @balpha ping me here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5/the-so-tavern-general

Comment: @balpha: sound works on chat.so, yes.

Comment: Hmm, http://cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/meta.ogg and http://sstatic.net/chat/meta.ogg seem empty in Chrome, but wgetting it works just fine. Weird.

Comment: Dear God please fix this or I'm going to have to pay attention to The Tavern.

Comment: @balpha I also notice that in Firefox, one request is made with a *200 OK* response. In Chrome, a request is made with a *200 OK* response showing in red and another request with a *206 Partial Content* response. Could be nothing, could be relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't ask me what exactly broke here, but for some reason Chrome 36 stopped playing the audio file with the chat.meta ping. I have re-encoded it while adding a bit of silence at the end, and voilà, it works again. It's magic!

Comment: The magic is magical. Thanks!

Comment: That's .. weird. Good job nonetheless! :)